# Email really sent or not?

Tags: email

My boss is saying that the emails I received from work are fraudulent, fake. Is there a way to verify if the emails were ever sent in the first place.

Comment: You received some emails and you are asking how to verify that they were sent? The existence of the emails are proof that they are sent. By someone, from somewhere. So, you are probably asking about the methods to **verify the origin and to validate the contents**.

Comment: what does "verify if the emails were sent mean"?

Comment: can it be proven that an email was generated then sent via the employers email system, is there a digital trail? and can the employer alter or even delete any digital trail to suit their own business purposes, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes Esa I am asking about methods to verify the origin and to validate the contents of an email. Can my employer manipulate their email server to suit their own interest, meaning: Can my employer delete proof that an email was ever generated or sent, thanks